# Why is my rails mysql broken when accessed through socket in rails only?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Update:  In fact when I just have a mySQL based app on its own, I still get the socket error -

Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)

So my mysql must be screwed up but I don't know how to fix it.  I can get into it totally ok through mysql and I can 'use' my database and select from tables at the mysql prompt.

But rails app or rails console I just can't get working.

I am trying to access both mysql and postgres databases but when I try to access mysql I get postgres information!
Note: I am trying to move 'to' postgres and I consider that to be the 'master' (if it counts) and mysql to be the source for old data that I am trying to get at (read only).

Specifically, I have a users table in each database.
I have the following in my database.yml file:

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  encoding: UTF8
  username: my_user_name

development:
  <<: *common
  database: newapp_development
  pool: 5

mysql_development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  username: my_user_name
  database: oldapp_development
```

I have a user table in postgres and a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have a users table in mysql and a User Model that I placed in a models/Mysql subdirectory.
It is still called user.rb but its contents are:

```
class Mysql::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "mysql_development"
end
```

However when I go into the console and do Mysql::User.all I get:

```
`[1] pry(main)> Mysql::User.all
(pry):1: warning: toplevel constant User referenced by Mysql::User
  User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"`
```

BUT...
the data returned is from postgres NOT mysql.  I can tell as the column names in the different user tables are totally different and there are only 5 records instead of the 464 I was expecting.

I'm sure that it must be possible but I just have the namespacing wrong or something but every combination I have tried has not worked so far.

I tried changing the directorty name to 'Oldapp' and the model name to OldApp::MysqlUser but when I do that and try Oldapp::MysqlUser.all I get

```
Mysql::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
from /Users/michaeldurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@ruby1.9.2_Abroad101/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:931:in `real_connect'
```

Comment: It might be very obvious thing to do. But have you restarted your server after changing the database.yml file?

Comment: it because of warning...Mysql::User == User.
try to rename Mysql directory and namespace to something else

Comment: Hi Phyo, good suggestion.  What I am doing is using the console and doing reload! each time to reload the environment.  I believe that should do what it says and reload the environment thus applying any changes

Comment: so when you renamed directory everything is good, now you use mysql connection!!! so fix database.yaml and add   host: localhost or needed host and everything will be fine!

Comment: I renamed the directory but still getting the socket error even though I can go directly into mysql, I can't use console or the app without getting the socket error.

Comment: Can you verify that your socket path is actually correct?  `mysql_config --socket` will show what it should be.

Comment: why don't you want just add host to yaml file?

Answer (score 2):

Can you add socket path in `mysql_development`:

```
  mysql_development:
    adapter: mysql
    encoding: utf8
    username: my_user_name
    database: oldapp_development
    socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

For finding socket path on your system please refer this file: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at what socket(s) your mysql server has *really* opened. First, you'll need mysql server pid :

```
PID=pidof mysqld
```

With this pid, you'll be able to see socket(s) mysql has opened :

```
lsof -p $PID | grep sock
```

You can after check path and rights to this socket.